# Bedroom light has become a master switch for 3 other lights

Tags: electrical

When I turn on the bedroom light(on a dimmer switch)it turns off lights in bedroom 2,kitchen and dining(also a dimmer).I've juggled the wiring so that sometime it's better,others worse but bedroom remains a master switch.All wires are in the dining switch.4 Earth,and 3 red live feeds.The live wires seem to be in the best places so my issue lies with the earths.Help please..confused

Comment: Based purely on what I read in your question, electrical wiring may not be a thing you are ready to DIY at this point. I'd firmly suggest an electrician as both safer for you and your house, and more likely to solve the problem than "juggling the wiring."

Answer (score 0):

Well if the ground is wrong then something else is wrong 
If you doing it by yourself start all over again but this time do one first it will lead you to the wiring problem